# How do I perform backpropagation in a Convolutional Neural Network with 2 convolutional layers?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

Specifically, I'm using a CNN for image classification and its architecture is:

data->conv1->pool1->conv2->pool2->classifier/softmax

When propagating errors from conv2 to pool1, how do I do that? I think that I have to convolve each channel from errors of conv2 with each filter and then add the results together to get the errors from pool1. Is that ok?